# Gimp "Failed to resize swap file: Invalid argument"

Tags: gimp, swap-file

Occasionally, when editing an image in GIMP, I'm shown the error message "***Failed to resize swap file: Invalid argument***".

After 5 seconds, this is usually followed by a second error "***unable to write tile data to disk: Invalid argument (-1/16384 bytes written)***"

[image: GIMP error messages]

Interestingly, this error doesn't cause GIMP to crash, nor does it seem to cause any visible issues. After closing the error window, I'm able to continue editing my current project in GIMP without any problems.

For reference, I'm using a 32-bit Windows 7 laptop with [GIMP Portable 2.8.22](https://portableapps.com/apps/graphics_pictures/gimp_portable) running off a 10.9 TB Network Drive. I suspect that running GIMP off a network drive may have something to do with the error.

**What does "Failed to resize swap file" mean? What's causing this error?**

Answer (score 3):

> What does "Failed to resize swap file" mean?

It's trying to resize it's swap/scratch/TileCache file, and it's failing.

> What's causing this error?

Hard to say, could be lots of reasons.  Low disk space, corrupted file system, dying hard drive, etc.  You also mention you're running Gimp over a Network connection, so the network connection may be too flakey for the swap files to work reliably.

Head to "Edit -> Preferences -> Folders -> Swap folder" in Gimp, set it to a folder on a local drive (that has lots of free space), and try again.

Comment: Could also be that network filesystems don't support the necessary methods to quickly [extend or truncate files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365698(v=vs.85).aspx) and it is what is failing.

Comment: FYI, the relevant code generating that error message lives at https://git.gnome.org/browse/gimp/tree/app/base/tile-swap.c?h=gimp-2-8#n717 ff and has some platform-specific parts for the truncating of the swap file, https://git.gnome.org/browse/gimp/tree/app/base/tile-swap.c?h=gimp-2-8#n153 ff. [The code hasn't changed in some years](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gimp/log/app/base/tile-swap.c?h=gimp-2-8), and I'm not aware of this kind of report, so I assume this usage scenario is pretty rare.